# Mocking method if one argument is raw and other may be from list

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I want to test if method was invoked X times with one raw argument and other arguments from list. I found this method:

```
    Mockito.verify(mock,Mockito.times(3)).myMethod(Mockito.eq("lastName"),
                   Mockito.argThat(Matchers.isOneOf("firstName","name","firstName"))));
```

However this complains that `argThat` method needs `ArgumentMatcher` but Matchers.isOneOf returns org.hamcrest.Matcher

Is there any other way that i could achieve this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

This changed in Mockito 2.1.0.  On the Mockito web site, there is this migration advice.

> All existing custom implementations of `ArgumentMatcher` will no longer
>   compile. All locations where hamcrest matchers are passed to `argThat()`
>   will no longer compile. There are 2 approaches to fix the problems:
>
> a) Refactor the hamcrest matcher to Mockito matcher: Use `implements
>   ArgumentMatcher` instead of `extends ArgumentMatcher`. Then refactor
>   `describeTo()` method into `toString()` method.
>
> b) Use `org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat()` instead of
>   `Mockito.argThat()`. Ensure that there is hamcrest dependency on
>   classpath (Mockito does not depend on hamcrest any more).
>
> What option
>   is right for you? If you don't mind compile dependency to hamcrest
>   then option b) is probably right for you. Your choice should not have
>   big impact and is fully reversible - you can choose different option
>   in future (and refactor the code)